# Filter table with dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, filtering, dropdown, onchange

I have a `table` and want to filter the last two columns, `Archived` and `Full Entry`. The 4th column archived will either have a date or be empty. The 5th column full entry will either be true or false. I have two dropdowns, the logic of the first dropdown should:

1. If Archived is selected, filter the 4th column to show only rows
   where 4th column is empty.
2. If Not archived is selected, filter 4th column to show only rows
   where 4th column is not empty.
3. If All selected, show all in this column

And

1. If True is selected for second dropdown, filter 5th column to show
   only rows where 5th column contains true.
2. .... If false filter 5th column where rows equal to false...
3. ... If all show all in 5th column.

I cannot get the script to work for Archive. Thanks for any help

```js
$(function() {
  $('#archive').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "archived") {
      $("#filter").find("td:nth-child(3):not(:empty)")
    } else {
      $("#filter").find("td:nth-child(3):empty")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="archive">Filter Archive</label>
<select id="archive" name="archive">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="archived">Archived</option>
  <option value="not-archived">Not Archived</option>
</select>

<label for="type">Filter Full Entry</label>
<select id="type" name="type">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="true" selected>True</option>
  <option value="false" selected>False</option>
</select>

<table class="table" style="width: 30%" id="filter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ref</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Archived</th>
      <th>Full Entry</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>True</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>False</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>True</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would  be much easy if you create table form array.

Comment: May I suggest using data-attributes. Just give a item data-archive="archived". Then we the user chooses that option, filter all that don't match?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is on the right lines, but just incomplete. Also note that the `archived` column is `nth-child(4)`, not `3`, as it's 1-based, not 0-based.

To simplify the logic you can create a function which runs when either of the filter `select` elements are changed. This function will first show all rows and then hide all those which do not match the filter option chosen, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#archive, #type').change(function() {
    filterTable($('#archive').val(), $('#type').val());
  });
});

function filterTable(archive, entry) {
  var $rows = $('#filter tbody tr').show();

  if (archive == "archived") {
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(4):empty)").hide()
  } else if (archive == "not-archived") {
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(4):not(:empty))").hide()
  }

  if (entry == "true") {
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(5):contains('False'))").hide()
  } else if (entry == "false") {
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(5):contains('True'))").hide()
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="archive">Filter Archive</label>
<select id="archive" name="archive">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="archived">Archived</option>
  <option value="not-archived">Not Archived</option>
</select>

<label for="type">Filter Full Entry</label>
<select id="type" name="type">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="true" selected>True</option>
  <option value="false" selected>False</option>
</select>

<table class="table" style="width: 30%" id="filter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ref</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Archived</th>
      <th>Full Entry</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>True</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>False</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>True</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean? This is filtering on all rows within the `tbody`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
$(function() {

  var $archive = $('#archive');
  var $type = $('#type');
  var $rows = $("#filter").find("tbody tr"); // cache this in a var for better performance (unless you have dynamic added rows)

  $archive.change(filterTable);
  $type.change(filterTable);

  function filterTable() {
    var archiveValue = $archive.val();
    var typeValue = $type.val();

    $rows.hide()                // hide all rows first
      .filter(function() {      // filter out the rows to show

      if (archiveValue === 'all' && typeValue === 'all') {
        return true; // show all rows if no filters selected
      } else if (archiveValue === 'all') {
        return $(this).children().eq(4).text().toLowerCase() === typeValue;  // show only matching type filters if archive filters is all
      } else {
        var text = $(this).children().eq(3).text().trim();
        isArchived = archiveValue === 'archived' ? text !== '' : text === ''; 
        if (typeValue === 'all') {
          return isArchived;             // if type filters is all, just show archive filtered contnt
        } else {
          return $(this).children().eq(4).text().toLowerCase() === typeValue && isArchived;  // filter by both archive and type
        }
      }

    }).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="archive">Filter Archive</label>
<select id="archive" name="archive">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="archived">Archived</option>
  <option value="not-archived">Not Archived</option>
</select>

<label for="type">Filter Full Entry</label>
<select id="type" name="type">
  <option value="all" selected>All</option>
  <option value="true">True</option>
  <option value="false">False</option>
</select>

<table class="table" style="width: 30%" id="filter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ref</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Archived</th>
      <th>Full Entry</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>True</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>False</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>True</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works thanks but both dropdowns do not filter together