# Using multiple dropdowns to filter HTML table

Tags: jquery, function, html-table, dropdown, onchange

I have two dropdowns used to filter my HTML table which works fine however the filters do not work together.
If I select Archive for example, the data is filtered correctly but when I select the other filter, it unfilters
then filters just the other filter. How can I make both work together or a cleaner way to implement this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#archive').change(function() {
    if (this.value == "archived") {
      $("#filter")
        .find("tbody tr")
        .hide()
        .filter(function() {
          return $(this).children('td').eq(3).text().trim() !== '';
        }).show();
    } else if (this.value == "not-archived") {

      $("#filter").find("tbody tr").hide().filter(function() {
        return $(this).children('td').eq(3).text().trim() === '';
      }).show();
    } else {
      $("#filter").find("tbody tr").show();
    }
  });

  $('#type').change(function() {
    if (this.value == "bookers") {
      $("#filter")
        .find("tbody tr")
        .hide()
        .filter(function() {
          return $(this).children('td').eq(4).text().trim() === 'True';
        }).show();
    } else if (this.value == "basics") {

      $("#filter").find("tbody tr").hide().filter(function() {
        return $(this).children('td').eq(4).text().trim() === 'False';
      }).show();
    } else {
      $("#filter").find("tbody tr").show();
    }
  });

  // show bookers by default
  $("#filter")
    .find("tbody tr")
    .hide()
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).children('td').eq(4).text().trim() === 'True';
    }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="type">Full Entry</label>
<select id="type" name="type">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="bookers" selected>Bookers</option>
  <option value="basics">Basics</option>
</select>

<label for="archive">Filter Archive</label>
<select id="archive" name="archive">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="archived">Archived</option>
  <option value="not-archived">Not Archived</option>
</select>

<table class="table" style="width: 30%" id="filter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ref</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Archived</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <th>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>03/04/12</td>
      <td>True</td>
    </th>
    <th>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>True</td>
    </th>
    <th>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>10/10/12</td>
      <td>False</td>
    </th>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The answer I provided in your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53867916/519413) already gives you this exact behaviour. Is there an issue with it...?

Comment: I also edited my previous answer to give you this behaviour in the previous question

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've kind of blind coded this but could you approach it like below?

One method to filter the items in one go.

```
<label for="type">Full Entry</label>
<select id="type" name="type" class="filter-field">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="bookers" selected>Bookers</option>
    <option value="basics">Basics</option>
</select>

<label for="archive">Filter Archive</label>
<select id="archive" name="archive" class="filter-field">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="archived">Archived</option>
    <option value="not-archived">Not Archived</option>
</select>

$(function () {
    $('.filter-field').change(function () {
        //get the values
        var _archived = $("#archived").val();
        var _type = $("#type").val();

        if(typeof _type == "undefined") _type = "bookers"; //show bookers by default

        $("#filter")
            .find("tbody tr")
            .hide()
            .filter(function () {
                var result = $(this).children('td');
                if(_archived == 'archived') {
                   result = result.eq(3).text().trim() !== '';
                } else if (_archived=='not-archived') {
                   result = result.eq(3).text().trim() === '';
                }
                if(_type=='bookers') {
                   result = result.eq(4).text().trim() === 'True';
                } else if(_type=='basics' {
                   result = result.eq(4).text().trim() === 'False';
                }

                return result;
            }).show();
    });

});
```

Comment: I get an error with result.eq is not a function when using them together